# FreeBSD ZFS: missing top-level device in zpool

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, freebsd, zfs

As a result of 2 stupid sysadmin tricks on a FreeBSD 10.4 machine, I have a non-importable zpool in this state:

```
# zpool import
   pool: v
     id: 5630710617833891462
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
 action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing
    devices and try again.
   see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-6X
 config:

    v                               UNAVAIL  missing device
      raidz2-0                      ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row3_Col1.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row2_Col2.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row1_Col1.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row3_Col3.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row1_Col2.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row3_Col2.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row3_Col4.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row2_Col3.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row1_Col3.eli  ONLINE
        gpt/vault_R0_Row4_Col1.eli  ONLINE
      gpt/vault_R0_Row2_Col1.eli    ONLINE

    Additional devices are known to be part of this pool, though their
    exact configuration cannot be determined.
```

The missing device exists in name, but the ZFS labels were cleared so ZFS won't accept it. The original sin was adding the last top-level device still visible and the missing one as top-level rather than into the raidz2-0 vdev. That was compounded by a desperate attempt to get ZFS to accept the removal of the now-missing geli device by destroying and recreating it.

The problem is that there is a substantial subset of the data in the raidz2-0 vdev which wasn't backed up (due to a different series of mistakes) and while it is not critical, I'd *like* to get it back. Also, the multiple TBs of data which *is* backed up is on tape in encrypted ZFS send streams, so restoration is a long chore.

As far as I can tell from documentation and from trying things like the '-F' and '-FX' options to `zfs import` and `zfs clear` without success, I'm basically out of luck. But am I, ***REALLY***? Is there really no way to tell ZFS that I don't care about the 2 accidentally added top-level devices that never had any real data written to them anyway? Maybe a way to edit the ZFS labels to make it think the zpool only has 1 child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a recent enough version of ZFS, you can import ZFS pools with missing top-level vdevs. To do so, you need to set `vfs.zfs.max_missing_tvds` to the numbers of missing top-level vdevs (1 in your case). The more vdevs are missing the more degraded the “experience” will be.

You should be able to adjust this value at runtime using `sysctl`:

```
sudo sysctl vfs.zfs.max_missing_tvds=1
```

Then, you can import the pool read-only:

```
sudo zpool import -o readonly=on your-pool
```

If you’re in luck, all datasets will mount. You should then be able to back up most data.

Afterwards, you can recreate the pool.

---

If you didn’t know about ZFS Pool Checkpoints, I suggest you look them up. They allow you to revert most operations on ZFS pools, including adding vdevs.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was on the verge of destroying the bad zpool and rebuilding when you answered, giving me hope. After upgrading the machine to FreeBSD 12.1 I also had to set vfs.zfs.max_missing_tvds_scan=1, but then I could import the pool. Everything of significant value appears to be accessible and I'm copying it all to a temporary zpool now. Luckily I had the needed 12TB of spare disk to do so.