# Can I read zpool with missing top level vdev?

Tags: zfs

I am new to ZFS and because of ignorance, I make terrible mistake. Delete zvol which is top level vdev of a pool. So I'm looking for a way to gather unbroken data from the pool.

Make long story short:

1. Make a pool with two raidz
2. Store some data(DataA)
3. Add zvol to the pool
4. Store some data(DataB)
5. Remove DataB
6. Remove zvol
7. Pool is degraded and looking for a way to read DataA

Here's long story begin:

I make a zpool with raidz and store some data(DataA). Suddenly I need more space to store some data (DataB) temporarily. I have extra zfs disk and I found 'zpool add' and 'zpool remove'. So I thought that 'It seems I could increase pool size by adding top level vdev and remove it later! It's perfect for me now!' and executed the plan. After removed DataB I found that 'zpool remove' could be done in very restricted situation.  I decided to rebuild pool. But I was in busy and needed to free space where zvol is occupying immediately. Cause DataA is stored before zvol is added, I thought that DataA is only striped in raidzs and even I delete zvol, DataA is readable. So I delete it. It was a really stupid idea.

The pool become DEGRADED and in-importable. I manage to import the pool by setting readonly on, zfs_max_missing_tvds to 1, spa_load_verify_data and spa_load_verify_metadata to False. But 'Permanent errors have been detected in the following files' error occurs on top level path and I can not mount pool.

Here's the current status of the pool.

[zpool status -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htiDp.png)

I'm planning some strategy but I can not figure out both how to and is it feasible. Here's some strategy:

- Find way to read data in current state.
- Make fake 'rv-part1' and import pool and do scrub
- Replace 'rv-part1' with other vdev and scrub
- Backup the pool and restore in working pool

To conclude, if there is a way or hint to restore my data please let me know and if you need any information, I'll provide it ASAP.

P.S.
It seems strange that raidz1-0 and raidz1-1 have same physical disk.... There's another stupid story....

Comment: This question is not on-topic here. Super User or Server Fault may be better.

Comment: Sorry for mistopic. Thanks for migration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FreeBSD ZFS: missing top-level device in zpool](https://superuser.com/questions/1592193/freebsd-zfs-missing-top-level-device-in-zpool)

Comment: @DanielB It's similar in some aspect. I already try the method in the article you mentioned and success to import the pool. But, unfortunately, as I mentioned in my question, top level directory('storage') is not readable. So it fails to mount the pool.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Should’ve read more carefully. You may be out of luck. I suggest trying the/a ZFS mailing list, preferably one where developers are around.

Comment: @DanielB Never mind it. I'm not familiar with mailing things, so I will searching for it. Thanks for suggestion.